# What is different between running gradle from CLI vs running it from Android studio GUI?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ffmpeg

Experiencing strange problem with gradle and Android Studio and I am not sure how to debug it. 
I have a gradle project and need ffmpeg. I am using process builder to get the path to ffmpeg. Here is code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"which", "ffmpeg"});
           process = pb.start();

if(process != null) {
            BufferedReader sdp = null;
            sdp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader serverConnection = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            ffmpegLocation = sdp.readLine();
            error1 = serverConnection.readLine();
        }
```

If it runs from Android Studio - ffmpegLocation is null 
If I run gradle from CLI - it finds ffmpeg and execute the code without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the answer. When ProcessBuilder is run from Android Studio/IntelliJ the PATH by default is empty. If it is run from cli - it uses my computer's path.